# drawInRect loses resolution when drawn to smaller image?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

When i draw a large image (say 1000x1000 pixel) using drawInRect method with size say 200x200 pixel and again i use drawInRect method to draw the image to its original size (1000x1000 pixel) does the resolution affect by using this ? Does the resolution decreases by drawing large image into small and again that same image to large image ?

Comment: Are you using the same UIImage to draw both?  Or using the image drawn from the 200x200 context to draw the new 1000x1000 context?

Comment: I am using the image drawn from 200x200 context to draw new 1000x1000 context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I've gotten your question correct in my head.

If you take an image bigger than 200x200 pixels and draw it into a 200x200 pixel rectangle, it'll get scaled down and lose most of its detail. If you then take the resultant image and try to draw it in a bigger rectangle it'll just get scaled up. So, to answer you're question, yes. It'll look blurry as hell. It's no different than resizing an image down in a graphics editor then blowing it back up to its original size. The loss of detail is permanent; there's no way to know what was lost in the transition down.

Comment: Can you suggest the proper way to scale the image.

Comment: Do you have the original image somewhere? Just draw a small image with that, then later when you need to draw it big again use the original for that, too. Of course, you could always store the image in a UIImageView and put that into a scroll view; the content itself isn't changed when that's zoomed in and out. Either way, you'll need to keep the original in memory. There's no way to get back the lost detail once it's scaled down and the original is gone. Once it's drawn into the context with less detail, anything derived from it will have less detail than the original.